# Can ElectricFlow be used for mobile app CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, electric-cloud

There is information of using Ship.io for Android and iOS CI but on accessing Ship.io "Server not found" error is returned. There are news of Beta version of Ship.io available: 
https://electric-cloud.com/company/news/press-releases/item/ship-io-launches-out-of-beta-electric-cloud-announces-commercial-availability-of-continuous-delivery-as-a-service-for-mobile-apps/

Is ElectricCloud/ElectricFlow used for web app CI/CD? If it can be used for mobiles is there any sample example to follow?

Any help on this lines will be of immense help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ElectricFlow can be used for mobile app CI.  It's practically unlimited in what it can orchestrate.  For example, I've worked with organizations using it to contribute to the Android Open Source Project which involved building and deploying the OS for numerous permutations of devices and their sub-components.